# What is the best way to share a variable across multiple threads?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a variable that I would like to be shared across multiple threads, and have it be incremented only once when all of the threads have used its current value. What is the best way to accomplish this in C?

Comment: it seems the perfect task for a semaphore: http://greenteapress.com/thinkos/html/thinkos012.html

Comment: rw locks have performance advantage over semaphores: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

Comment: I think there are two questions/problems you need to solve: 1) how do you tell when all the threads have used the current value once?  And 2) how does any particular thread tell if it has already used the current value?  For #1, if you know the number of threads, you can have each thread count down when it uses the value.  (Semaphore works for this.)  For #2, a thread can either remember the last value it used, and not run again until the value is different, or you can have a "serial number" for a value, and increment _that_ when the value is changed.

Comment: It depends at least on three things. First, you have to know the number of threads beforehand. Second, can the threads wait until they are allowed to change the value? What thread will actually change the variable?

Comment: "all of the threads have used its current value". Looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: You can code a service/daemon that manages access to the variable. Each task register itself to the service/daemon and so it can know how many tasks it has to waits for and gives access to variable value trough a IPC communication: e.g. a socket. BTW your question is OT because it is opinion based.

Comment: Without a definition of "best", your question only invites opinions, is thus off-topic. Anyhow, what possible ways has the research you have made turned up?